# Given a String, return an array of char values that contains the characters of the string in reverse order

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, char

From the title you can see what I'm trying to do, however it's not working and I'm not sure why. Who has any ideas or simpler way to do this method?
(without using string builder and all that extra stuff)

```
public char[] reverseStringToArray(String str)
{

   char[] reverseStringToArray  = str.toCharArray();

   char[] characters = new char[reverseStringToArray.length];

   for (int i = reverseStringToArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)

       characters[i] = reverseStringToArray[i];

   return reverseStringToArray;
}
```

Comment: Here `characters[i] = reverseStringToArray[i];` those indices should be *different*. I'll leave it to you to figure out what they should be, but it's very simple math.

Comment: Also this `return reverseStringToArray[i];` shouldn't compile!

Comment: Side question -- why are you using `Character` and not `char`? A `Character[]` array is not the same as a `char[]` array.

Answer (score 2):

[`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) has a useful method [`reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse--), you can use that and then convert to a `char[]`. Like,

```
return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString().toCharArray();
```

If you must implement your own array reverse here, it's important to know not to reverse elements beyond the half-way mark (why? because you will reverse them and then reverse them back). Note that you also need to perform a full swap or you'll lose half of your input. That is, it should look something like,

```
char[] rsa = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < rsa.length / 2; i++) {
    char ch = rsa[i];
    rsa[i] = rsa[rsa.length - i - 1];
    rsa[rsa.length - i - 1] = ch;
}
return rsa;
```